# Brag points added to Careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

One of the things people do is speak at conferences, guest lectures, devdays, etc.

I would like the ability to denote that kind of accomplishment on careers.

In the general case, it would be useful if there was a kind of list of 'one-off' achievements that could be described. E.g., "I got the chief pony groomer award at TXI Studios"

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the freeform fields available on the CV already.

Maybe you're looking to have a separate box to hold "random achievements"? I'd stick them in the "what else do you want to brag about yourself" box, myself. (aka "projects and links")

Answer (score 1):

*YOU GOT THE CHIEF PONY GROO...*

oh.

But seriously, the "projects and links" area should be OK for this.

Comment: I'm not so sure about this.  For example, If I was a school winner in an Invitational Mathematics Competition, that's not really a project...

Comment: Don't make them rename "Projects and Links" to Misc" or "Other" ;)

Comment: @Danny Tuppeny -- You can add headers to the Projects and Links area using Markdown, but it looks a little funky as it is not quite lined up with the other main headers. I added a Papers and Publications section at the end of my "Background". It looks like this: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/publish/11686